# VB Script if statement: Sub not defined

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, wsh, vb-like-operator

I have the code below

```
if (LCase(Config_(C_))) like "show*" Then
crt.screen.send Config_(C_) & VBCR
crt.screen.WaitForStrings ">", "#"
End If
```

but when I run it I get a "Sub not defined on line 36 (which is the "if(LCase(....." line)

`Config_` is an array of strings 
`C_` is the element address

So all I want to do is say,

If this array element starts with "show" then run the command, insuring it does not matter if the user emters upper or lower case.

Why this code does not work? Other if like statements seem ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no `like` statement in vbscript. You could use `Left` which will return n number of characters at the start of a string and see if the string it return equals "show"  -

```
if Left(LCase(Config_(C_)),4) = "show" Then
```

Comment: Ahh that will be it then! I have been playing with VBA for last few months, and must have been thinking of that when I say it worked for other cases. Thank you for the example code :)

Answer (score 1):

The work "LIKE" is not a key word or a function in vbscript